# SSH login without password not working from rc.local

Tags: ssh, startup

I have created a bash script as follows and saved it as `/usr/bin/db.sync.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

rsync -ar --delete /files/database_backups slyme@192.168.1.4:/users/slyme/Documents/server_backups
```

I have generated the necessary pair of authentication keys to make this work without the need to enter a password.

When I run the command directly it works (hurrah!).

I have added the following to `/etc/rc.local':

```
/usr/bin/db.sync.sh >>/files/database_backups/db-sync.log.txt 2>&1
```

When I restart the machine this script fails and the log file suggests that the process asks for a password which, of course, it doesn't get so it fails. If I run `/etc/rc.local` from the command line then, sure enough, I get asked for a password and when I enter it the script works.

Anyone got any ideas why the script needs a password when run from rc.local even though it doesn't need a password when run directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script /etc/rc.local is run as root. Make sure that you have the correct private key for user slyme@192.168.1.4 installed in /root/.ssh/ (and not just in your user's $HOME/.ssh)

Alternatively, to make sure the correct private key is used, you can specify it on the rsync command line:

```
rsync -e "ssh -i /path/to/ssh_key" ...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I copied the key to the root account. It worked. Thank you. This was the last step in what (for me) was a long process of configuring a development server just the way I want it. I am very happy with the outcome.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `/etc/rc.local` you should run the script as your user:

```
su -l myuser -c /path/to/the/script
```

Otherwise, you can use the `@startup` option of the `cron` system; this way the job is safely executed as your user and you do not need to edit system files. See for example https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57852/crontab-job-start-1-min-after-reboot

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion re user, I shall try it out. I can't use a cron job for this without a lot of fiddling about because a script that this one relies on (to create the files in the first place) needs mysql to be up and running before it executes